# JavaScript: Check / Compare values of all fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, compare

In my JavaScript function I give all input-, textarea- and select-fields the actual value as an `initial_value`:

```
$('input, textarea, select').each(function (i) {
    $(this).data('initial_value', $(this).val());
});
```

So I can check by `keyup` if there are any changes in a field:

```
$("body").on("keyup", 'input, textarea, select', function() {
    if ($(this).val() != $(this).data('initial_value')) {
        handleFormChanged();
        changeMessage();
    }
});
```

But also I want to check by `keyup` if the changes were deleted out of the fields. My idea was to check with an `else if` if the value in all fields is equal to the `initial_value` in all fields. It is important to know if really the value in ALL fields is equal to the `initial_value`. But it doesn´t work. Any better ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _changes were deleted out of the fields_

Comment: For example: I open a new page and have two empty input-fields. Both of them are empty and this is the `intial_value`. If I type something in one of the fields, the if-loop is executed because in one of the fields the value is not equal to the `initial_value`. Now I delete this "something" I typed into the field and want to check again, if the value is now equal to the `initial_value`. And this I want to check for all fields.

Comment: So, you'd like to update initial value whenever you add/delete/modify input fields?

Comment: No, the `initial_value` is set only once when the page gets loaded. Then the `initial_value` is there to compare with the actual value if equal or not. And this comparison is my problem. I don´t know how to compare if the value of all fields is equal to the `inital_value` of all fields.

Comment: Exactly! I will try to make it more clear: I have a few fields and if in one of them is a change `changeMessage();` displays a message for the user that there are unsaved changes. But if the user removes his typed text out of the input field the message should be no longer displayed. That´s the reason why I need to check if in all my fields are no more changes. I need it for all fields because if the user changes in two fields something and only removes it in one of them, there are still changes on the page and the else if-loop should not be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as per your comments, I'd assume that you'd like to compare each input's `value` against it's own `initial value` and see if all of them match. If not, you'd like to call your methods.

So, you need to iterate thru all inputs within the `keyup` handler, probably generate an `array` with custom values (`yes` => value and initial value match, `no` => value and initial value don't match) based on the condition being satisfied using [`$.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/). Later on, you may use [`$.inArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) to see if a *no-match value* (`"no"` in this case) exists and act accordingly. Below is a demo as to how this could be accomplished.

```js
var allInputs = 'input, textarea, select';

$(allInputs).each(function (i) {
    $(this).data('initial_value', $(this).val());
});

$("body").on("keyup", allInputs, function() {
    
    var matches = $(allInputs).map(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        return $this.val() === $this.data('initial_value') && "yes" || "no";
    }).get();
    
    //The below is only for the purpose of demo
    $("div").html( JSON.stringify(matches, null, 4) );
    //alert ("Each input is equal to it's inital_value: " + ($.inArray("no", matches) === -1));
    // - End of demo --
    
    //So, do your stuff when the condition is met
    if ($.inArray("no", matches) > -1) {
        handleFormChanged();
        changeMessage();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input ttype="text" />
<input ttype="text" value="10" />
<textarea></textarea>

<div></div>
```